# Why does removing and newly adding a child component invoke an ObjectUnsubscribedError?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject, angular8

In a *parent component* I have a list:

```
items: SomeType;
```

This list gets it values from a service:

```
this.someService.items$.subscribe(items => {
  this.items = items;
});
```

At some point this list is updated with new criteria:

```
this.someService.getData(this.criteria);
```

This works fine.

---

There's also a *child component* which is inserted for every element in that list:

```
<ul *ngFor="for let item of items">
  <app-list-item [item]="item"></app-list-item>
</ul>
```

This works fine too, but only for the first time `this.items` in the *parent component* is loaded.

The *child component* does also get values from a service:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.someOtherService.mapping$.subscribe(mapping => {
    this.mapping = mapping;
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.someOtherService.mapping$.unsubscribe();
}
```

When the criterias in the *parent component* change and the list of items is loaded again, the *child component* fails with this error message:

> Error
>   message: "object unsubscribed"
>   name: "ObjectUnsubscribedError"

When I remove `this.someOtherService.mapping$.unsubscribe();` in the *child component's* `ngOnDestroy` method, it works again. But shouldn't I not `unsubscribe`, when the component gets destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you unsubscribe on child is not correct. you are unsubscribing from the observable, not subscription. it should be;

```js
sosSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.sosSubscription = this.someOtherService.mapping$.subscribe(mapping => {
    this.mapping = mapping;
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sosSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I thought I can skip to add an extra variable, if I unsubscribe from the BehaviorSubject directly.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51895190/1209097) is a good example that explains what happens when you unsubscribe from a Subject.